# Newly created Flutter / Android project fails to build

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build a newly created Android project (created using `flutter create`), but the gradle build because of missing dependencies.

I have tried to install a newer version of gradle (using `brew install gradle`) and tried to change it to that (5.4.1) version without luck. I also read in multiple places that the problem might be a conflict of different `httpclient` versions being in the class path, but is not the case. I have also tried adding the httpclient dependency directly to the root build.gradle file, but the error remains.

`build.grade (root)`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
                // classpath 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.8'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Expected result: `build finished`.

Actual result: gradle build exception;

```
[   +3 ms] * Error running Gradle:
           ProcessException: Process "/Users/riccardo/dev/app/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

           FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

           * What went wrong:
           A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
           > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
              > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
                Required by:
                    project :
                 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
                    > Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
                 > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0.
                    > Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
```

How do install this missing dependency? Shouldn't it be fetched from jcenter for instance?

Answer (score 0):

change the `buildscript` to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        // google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Exact same error appears (with 2.3.0 replaced by 3.4.0 obviously).

Comment: @riccardo_92 `2.3.0` does not know repository `google()`... I don't even think that flutter project is "new", when it uses such outdated versions. the [current version](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels) is 1.2.1.

Comment: I used 3.4.0 like you said. The Flutter project was created today.

Comment: @riccardo_92 "created today" has little to do with the flutter version. installing or updating gradle (wrapper) might be required.

Comment: clear; I also installed latest Flutter lib today. I'll try updating gradle wrapper.

Comment: Updated gradle (wrapper) to 5.4.1 and error slightly changes but boils down to the same thing:
           * What went wrong:
           Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory